# Out-gridview does not sorting results

Tags: powershell, out-gridview

I have a script that I am trying to collect drive letters from a list of servers (as well as used space and free space) and then gridview the results out.

```
$servers = Get-Content "path.txt"

foreach ($server in $servers) {
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server {Get-PSDrive | Where {$_.Free -gt 0}}

Select-Object -InputObject usedspace,freespace,root,pscomputername |
Sort-Object root -Descending | Out-Gridview
}
```

I can get it to display the drive information for each server on the list but gridview does not work.  I have tried moving the brackets around (before and after gridview) as well as piping elements but have had no luck.

Can anyone advise me as to what I am doing wrong?  I feel like it is something simple but all of the examples I am finding online do not use the foreach command which I think has to do with throwing it off.

Comment: What's the error message? You have a typo in your `Select-Object` command by the way, it should be `-Descending` and not `-Decending`

Comment: You aren't piping to select-object.

Comment: Im not getting any errors.  It does out put the information but in the ISE screen rather than the Out-GridView window.  The typo was my fault.  it is spelled correctly in the script.  I had to retype due to separation of networks.

Comment: @js2010 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server {Get-PSDrive | Where {$_.Free -gt 0}} |  
 yields an error "The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input"

Answer (score 3):

- Your [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) is missing pipeline input - pipe the [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) call's output to it.
- Instead of `-InputObject`, use `-Property`:

  - Note: `-InputObject` is the parameter that facilitates *pipeline* input, and is usually not meant to be used *directly*.
  - As with [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object), `-Property` is the first *positional* parameter, so you may omit `-Property` in the call below.

```bash
foreach ($server in Get-Content "path.txt") {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server { Get-PSDrive | Where { $_.Free -gt 0 } } |
    Select-Object -Property usedspace, freespace, root, pscomputername |
    Sort-Object root -Descending |
    Out-Gridview
}
```

Also note that `-ComputerName` can accept an *array* of computer names, which are then queried *in parallel*, so if you want to query all computers and then call `Out-GridView` only *once*, for the results from *all* targeted computers:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content "path.txt") { 
    Get-PSDrive | Where Free -gt 0 
  } |
  Select-Object -Property usedspace, freespace, root, pscomputername |
  Sort-Object root -Descending |
  Out-Gridview
```

To group the results by target computer, use
`Sort-Object pscomputername, root -Descending`

---

If you'd rather stick with your sequential, target-one-server-at-a-time approach, change from a [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach)  - which cannot be used directly as pipeline input - to a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call, which allows you to pipe to a *single* `Out-GridView` call:

```bash
Get-Content "path.txt" | 
  ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ { Get-PSDrive | Where Free -gt 0 }
  } |  
 Select-Object -Property usedspace, freespace, root, pscomputername |
 Sort-Object root -Descending |
 Out-Gridview
```